# Ordered Sampling with Replacement

Tags: java, combinatorics

Im really stuck in a rut for this one.

I want generate all the combinations such that there is Ordered Sampling with Replacement (i think this is what its called, see my example) and the result is output in an array of arrays (2D array).

For example

```
public static int[][] combinations(int n, int k)
```

on input n=3, k=2 would give:

[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]

I'm really unsure how to do this efficiently. Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Could we see your code?

Comment: "Ordered sampling with replacement" looks equivalent to the [cartesian power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_power) `{0..n-1}^k`

Comment: @suspicousdog yeah turns out it was just cartesian product. I just didn't know it was called that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we have a set with `n` elements and we want to draw `k` samples from the set such that ordering matters and repetition is allowed.

Here the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 4;
    int k = 2;
    int[][] result = combinations(n, k);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
    //this will print:
    //[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,0],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
}

public static int[][] combinations(int n, int k) {
    int[] nArray = IntStream.range(0, n).toArray();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    combinationStrings(k, nArray, "", list);
    return fromArrayListToArray(list, k);
}

private static void combinationStrings(int k, int[] nArray, String currentString, List<String> list) {
    if (currentString.length() == k) {
        list.add(currentString);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++) {
            String oldCurrent = currentString;
            currentString += nArray[i];
            combinationStrings(k, nArray, currentString, list);
            currentString = oldCurrent;
        }
    }
}

private static int[][] fromArrayListToArray(List<String> list, int k) {
    int[][] result = new int[list.size()][k];
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
        String[] split = list.get(i).split("\\B");
        for (int j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {
            result[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(split[j]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```